# Opening bufferedimage and drawing over using objects

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I am trying to open a bufferedimage file that I have saved which was created using a very simple paint program that uses objects stored in an array list. However, when I open the file (png), I get the following error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D cannot be cast to Shape

I am trying to simply open the file and then store it in a new ArrayList (wiping the previous clean), but also allowing it to be edited. What do I need to do to make such a conversion?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics page) {
    super.paintComponent(page);
    if (drawnItems.size() > 0)
      for (int index = 0; index <= drawnItems.size() - 1; index++)
        ((Shape) drawnItems.get(index)).draw(page);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code, where you try to save a BufferedImage as a "Shape" in an ArrayList?

Comment: There's only one cast in the code you have posted, so to me the error is pretty obvious... It seems you simply have `Graphics2D` objects in your `drawnItems` list. The problem is likely the part where you put items into the list, not the code you have posted, which is simply accessing them. Generics could help you get compile time checking of this.

Comment: The file is being opened using a `JFileChooser` dialog. `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(String.valueOf(file)));
drawingPanel.drawnItems.add(img);`

Comment: I am not familiar enough with generics at the moment :(

Comment: For what it's worth, I solved this by using TexturePaint to paint my image over an object which actually works even better than what I was initially trying to do